# Symfony/QueryBuilder: "myEntityAlias.myEntity.id" <- possible?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine

In short:

I'd like to fire a SQL-Query like below with something like `s.item.id`. Is this possible?

**Entities**:

```
class Set {
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="myBundle\Entity\Item")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $item;

    // ...
}
```

...

```
class Item {
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    */
    protected $id;

    // ...
}
```

**Repository**

```
$sql = '
    SELECT i.id, s.name 
      FROM mybundle:Item i, mybundle:Set s 
     WHERE s.item.id = i.id <---------------------- !!!
';

return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder($sql)
            ->getResult();
```

Comment: Yes it is possible though sadly you will have to invest a bit of time learning how Doctrine 2 builds queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it?
I prefer to use the query builder functions as [referenced here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) though.
Something like this may work for you:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('i.id, s.name')
   ->from('mybundle:Item', 'i')
   ->leftJoin('mybundle:Set', 's', 'WITH', 's.item_id = i.id');
```

Edit: SQL query should be something like `SELECT i.id, s.name FROM items i LEFT JOIN sets s ON s.item_id = i.id`, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Actually, the code you posted won't even come close to working.  You will need a left join in there.